# Forcing Javascript numbers to Double in MongoDB document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to save an arbitrary Javascript Object to a MongoDB Document, but I want all the numbers to be type Double in the database.
All the fields which aren't arrays or objects will be strings or numbers.

For example:

```
{ "things": [ 1.0, 1.1, [ { "item": 6 }, 5.5, "test" ] ],
  "other things": { "thing": 2.0, "other thing" : [ 4.4, 5.0 ] },
  "another thing": 6.0 }
}
```

The nodejs-mongodb-native driver saves numbers which it can (e.g. 5.0) as Int32.

I can force the numbers to be doubles by replacing them with Double objects:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
new mongo.Double(number);
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this than recursively walking through the entire Javascript object
replacing each number with a mongo.Double object?

Comment: why do you want them to be doubles in the database?

Comment: The default storage in the database is actually as doubles or floats as most say (that is the default storage of numbers in MongoDB), the helper is exactly that and is prolly only needed for 64bit floats or negative floats or whatever.

Comment: Philipp, yes, I want Doubles but numbers which can be integers are coming in as Int32.

Comment: Sammaye, maybe it's a function of the node-mongodb-native driver, but some numbers are saved as Int32.

Comment: **why** do you want them to be doubles in the database?

Comment: 5.0 will be saved as an int I believe, but 4.4 shouldn't be, sometimes better to get the application to handle that

Comment: Philipp, because the data is used by a Java application (which I cannot modify) that expects Doubles.

Comment: Sammaye, that's right, 4.4 is saved as Double, 5.0 as Int32. I don't have access to the application which consumes the data and requires Doubles.

Comment: Ah that's crappy, bad programming if it requires doubles, something that in binary is impossible with true precision, hmmm yea you method of recursively walking is the only method I see

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to replace the variables with mongo.Double throughout your code. It's sufficient to do so when you create the document you store in your database. Using an object-relational mapping framework could also help you with that.

When you want to store your Javascript objects as they are in the database and don't have an intermediate database-version of the objects, you could create a wrapper function to save objects to MongoDB which creates a deep-copy of the object, but stores all integers in the source document in mongo.Double's in the target document. The target document is then saved to the database.

Comment: That's the way of doing it I was wondering if I could avoid: Walking through the entire arbitrarily deep object and replacing numbers with mongo.Double's.

Comment: What kind of solution did you expect? MongoDB is schemaless. You can't tell it that db.collections.doc.field.subfield.subsubfield must always be double.

Comment: Philipp, I don't know if there is a better way than writing a routine which traverses the entire object and changes each number to a mongo.Double object, which is why I asked the question.